# How to stop a picklist from being controlled by record type?

Tags: picklist, record-type

So we have been working with one master record type for a long time, where adding values to a picklist at Object level simply made the values appear automatically where that picklist was used.

Recently, we split our records into two record types.  Record type A does not use the picklist in question at all, while Record type B has the picklist on it's page.

What the issue is, is that when adding values to the picklist field at Object level, those values don't get added to the actual visible field till you add the values both in the picklist field on the Object and in the Record Type picklist.

This is super-annoying, as we don't have our record types share picklists that we need to change values in based on record types.

I need values that are added to picklists at Object level to appear as available selection choices the moment I add those values.

Is there a way to do this, or are we forever stuck now with a 2-step process to add values to picklists now? (even if that picklist is used on only 1 record type to begin with)

Is there a way to stop the picklist form being controlled by record type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the product stands today, the two-step process is currently required; you can't have picklists that automatically ignore record types. However, there is an idea you'll want to vote on: [Show picklist values across all record types](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1CAAS).

Comment: I see what you mean.  I voted on that idea but it's not terribly clear and 7 years old.  So I wrote up my own idea with as much clarity if I could, even if it didn't retain paragraph breaks.  It's right here:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DxVAAA0